# Loop within a print statement

Tags: python, loops, printing

```
import sys
outfile = open( r'/Users/x/Desktop/myDoc.txt', 'w' )
    i = 0
    lis = []
    n = int(raw_input("How many interviews are there? "))
    while n:
       i += 1
       istart = raw_input("Interview Start Time: ")
       iend= raw_input("Interview End Time: ")
       ipeople= raw_input("What are the interviewer names: ")
       itype= raw_input("What is the interview type: ")
       lis.append((istart, iend, ipeople, itype))
       n-=1
    a = "<html><head></head><body><TABLE border=1><TR> </TR> <TR>\
        <TH>Start</TH>\
        <th>End</th>\
        <th>People</th>\
        <TH>Interview Type</TH></TR><TR ALIGN=CENTER></TR> \
        <td>fff</td>dd<td>dddd</td><td>ddd</td><td>ddddd</td></TABLE></body></html>"

    outfile.write(a)
outfile.close()
```

So basically this print statement is writing to a file on my computer but I am running into a problem of including another loop within this print statement since if the user says there are 5 interviews I need 5 rows where each row is one tuple within the list and each column is each item within that tuple (and if the user says 6 interviews I need 6 rows and so on). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Where is the print statement?

Comment: added it to the above

Comment: not solving your problem but the while loop and increments are not very pretty. why not replacing it with `for i in xrange(n):` => no need to increment i or n manually. also, it is safer: in your case, if the user enters a negative number, you end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem? The loop only has to create the rows, you should not put start and end of the document inside the loop.

```
import sys
outfile = open( r'/Users/x/Desktop/myDoc.txt', 'w' )
i = 0
lis = []
n = int(raw_input("How many interviews are there? "))
table = "<html><head></head><body><TABLE border=1><TR>\
    <TH>Start</TH>\
    <th>End</th>\
    <th>People</th>\
    <TH>Interview Type</TH></TR><TR ALIGN=CENTER></TR> \
    %s</TABLE></body></html>"

while n:
   i += 1
   istart = raw_input("Interview Start Time: ")
   iend= raw_input("Interview End Time: ")
   ipeople= raw_input("What are the interviewer names: ")
   itype= raw_input("What is the interview type: ")
   lis.append("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (istart, iend, ipeople, itype))
   n-=1



outfile.write(table % ''.join(lis))
outfile.close()
```

Instead of "while n" you could use range(n), then you don't need any counter variable.